# How to determine what type is returned by concatwith angular store

Tags: angular, return, concatenation, ngrx, store

Hi have 2 observables ,

1. this.resolveActifsFromStore() // return Observable
2. this.store.select(fromActifSelector.DoSelector.selectAllActifs) // return Observable<IActifModel[]>

I need to execute by order, so I use the concatWith like this

```
actifs$!: Observable<IActifModel[]>;

ngOnInit(){
    this.resolveActifsFromStore()
    .pipe(        
        concatWith(this.store.select(fromActifSelector.DoSelector.selectAllActifs)),
    )        
    .subscribe((val)=>{ 
              //error first return is boolean , the second is  IActifModel[]
              //HERE IS I DON´T KNOW HOW TO DO 
              if(val) { 
                        actifs$ = of(val);
                      } 
}
```

The problem is the val will have the return boolean, and also IActifModel[].
How can I identify the type of each return, because I want to do this, if the first observables is true then I want to assign the value of the second observable to actifs$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `concatMap` to wait for the first observable to complete and then proceed to the second one:

```js
this.resolveActifsFromStore().pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromActifSelector.DoSelector.selectAllActifs),
  concatMap(([myBoolean, myIActifModel]: [boolean, IActifModel[]]) => {
    //....
    return of({
       theBoolean: myBoolean,
       theOtherOne: myIActifModel
    });
  })
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Or based on your post, you could also use `forkJoin` and see when the value is `true` do some logic with it...

```js
const total$ = forkJoin({
  theBoolean: this.resolveActifsFromStore(),
  theOtherOne: this.store.select(fromActifSelector.DoSelector.selectAllActifs)
});

total$.subscribe(({theBoolean, theOtherOne}) => {
   if (theBoolean) {
     //... do some logic 
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andres2142, seem to me your solution is right one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.isArray`. It inferes the type correctly and knows within the if block, that the type of val is an array.(https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```
.subscribe((val: boolean | IActifModel[])=>{ 
    if(Array.isArray(val)) {
      // code for IActifModel[]
    } else {
      // code for boolean
    }
```

Comment: Hi MoxxiManagarm, thanks, is working now. One last question I don´t think my approach is correct , There is another way to do what I want with another kind of code ?  Best practise